# How to add/edit tag of an asset from another asset library using python (add-on)?

Tags: python, scripting, asset-browser

[This link specifies how to add a new tag to an asset present in current file.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249316/python-set-asset-library-tags-and-catalogs)

After adding a new asset library, I want to add a tag to the assets present in that library.

[This link mentions that it is not possible through Blender UI and it also mentions that it is possible through add-ons.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/asset_libraries/introduction.html#cross-blend-file-editing)

```
asset_libraries = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries
for asset_library in asset_libraries:
    library_name = asset_library.name
    library_path = Path(asset_library.path)
    blend_files = [fp for fp in library_path.glob("**/*.blend") if fp.is_file()]

    for blend_file in blend_files:
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(str(blend_file)) as (file_contents, data_to):
            print('file_content objects : ', file_contents.objects)
```

The above code prints an array of strings, i.e., all object names.

I want access to the object itself, in order to add a new tag to it.

Any help or direction would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bpy.data.libraries.load` lets you *import* items in your current file, but it doesn't let you *modify* the data in the other files (AFAIK). So unfortunately you do have to individually open all these files, add the tags, then save the files.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

tag_name = "My new tag"

asset_libraries = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries
for asset_library in asset_libraries:
    library_name = asset_library.name
    library_path = Path(asset_library.path)
    blend_files = [fp for fp in library_path.glob("**/*.blend") if fp.is_file()]

    for blend_file in blend_files:
        bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=str(blend_file))
        for obj in bpy.data.objects:
            if not obj.asset_data:
                continue
            obj.asset_data.tags.new(tag_name, skip_if_exists=True)
        bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AssetTags.html#bpy.types.AssetTags)

Plugging my (free) addon which lets you batch set tags, author and other good stuff from libraries from the Asset Browser interface :

https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities

Comment: I have updated the code and it is crashing on open_mainfile() in add-on.

Comment: @KarthikNagaraj It's best not to modify the question too much because then the answers becomes irrelevant :) Without seeing more of your addon code it's hard to say why exactly this happens. Usually these kind of crashes come from the context not being initialized correctly. Using a timer to pause the script a little bit can help : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: 2) I am using `from pathlib import Path` whereas, your code uses `from pathutils import Path` and usind your import gives me error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathutils'

Comment: With a couple of timers, I was able to open multiple blend files one by one, add tags to all assets, save the blend files and re-open the original file(where the script execution started).
Thanks @Gorgious

Comment: @KarthikNagaraj glad it helped ! If you want to, you can modify my answer or add a new one to showcase your solution, might help other people in the future. Cheers :)