# How to get tag/description of an asset that's placed in a scene using python

Tags: python, asset-browser, asset

From this question, I understand to set a tag of an asset we need to open the Blend file.
[How to add/edit tag of an asset from another asset library using python (add-on)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251473/how-to-add-edit-tag-of-an-asset-from-another-asset-library-using-python-add-on)

But can we get / access a tag of an asset when it's placed/instanced in a scene?

I tried this simple code on object named "Foo" and it return the description if we do it from the asset blend file. But it's not working when the asset is placed in another blend file

```
import bpy

for coll in bpy.data.collections:
    if (coll.name == "Foo"):
        print (coll.asset_data.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

`bpy.data.materials['Material'].asset_data.tags.new('Material Tag')`

Comment: Seriously? If the answer contributes to the solution, you will receive a prize for the shortest answer ever given here on Blender SE. ;-) It would definitely help if you could explain a little more about this so others can better understand why this works, right?