# Get Asset Browser catalogs in case of unsaved changes

Tags: python, add-on, asset-browser

My goal is to create new catalogs in the Asset Browser via Python in an addon for Blender. Additionally, I want to set sensible names for the catalogs.

I know I can add a new catalog via `bpy.ops.asset.catalog_new()`, but I cannot specify the catalogs name in this call. No problem, if I can rename the newly created catalog, but the function call does not return any information/handle of the newly created catalog. I would like to circumvent this by getting all catalogs before and after the function call, compare them and the difference must be the newly created one.

But: How can I get the currently available catalogs? I found a solution how to get the catalogs from a saved file here: [Python - Set Asset Library Tags and Catalogs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249316/python-set-asset-library-tags-and-catalogs)
However, I don't want to save the catalogs before and after adding the new one and load the catalog files just in order to get a handle of the new catalog. That appears overly convoluted to me and the saving might be unexpected for the addon user. I hope there is an easier solution.

Comment: Hello ! I'm not that familiar with catalogs ops API, have you explored [catalogs_save](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.asset.html#bpy.ops.asset.catalogs_save) ? I have a feeling until the catalog definition is saved the catalogs are stored temporarily somewhere in memory and you can't access it with the python API

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, I tried `catalogs_save()`, but that saves the catalogs to disk, which I want to circumvent, if possible. Saving the catalogs to disk would be a side effect a user might not expect.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's bad design. I don't think you can do what you're after without the side effects then